# How can I adjust the vertical position a font awesome icon?

Tags: html, css

I have font awesome icon like so:

```
<div>
    <span >Total</span>
    <i class="cat-color fa fa-circle" style="color: darkorange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>11</span>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1519/
Basically I want to have the option to move up or down the icon. I've tried adding in padding and margins, but nothing there.

How can I change the vertical position of the icon?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post your CSS?  Generally font-awesome sets display for the "i" element to inline.  I usually set it to inline-block or block depending on what I am trying to position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also just use line-height and vertical-align like so:

```
.cat-color {
  line-height: 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

And change the line height to a higher or lower value, to move the icon up  or down.

I have made it move up.

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1520/

Comment: Do check if it works cross browser, for the browsers you care about. I only checked this in chrome and IE Edge.

Comment: All my webfont icons were shifted up too far, so I used `vertical-align: middle;` on the webfont class to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

Relative positioning:

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cat-color.fa::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="all-incidents-count">
  <span>Total</span>
  <i class="cat-color fa fa-circle" style="color: darkorange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>11</span>
```

Comment: i'm getting the icon well below the texts in your demo, that's why I said so

Comment: That's where it's supposed to be...the vertical position has been adjusted as required by the OP.  Just change the top value to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
i {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: .2s
}
div:hover > i {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="all-incidents-count">
  <span>Hover</span>
  <i class="cat-color fa fa-circle" style="color: darkorange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>me!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is Kode_12 using flex?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Using `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align`

see more here : [CSS vertical-align Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

```css
.fa {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
span {
  display:inline-block;
  height:150px;
  }
div {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <span >Total</span>
    <i class="cat-color fa fa-circle" style="color: darkorange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>11</span>
</div>
```

**2.** Using `position:relative;` and `top:`

see more here [CSS position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

```css
.fa {
  position:relative;
  top:80%;
}
div {
  background:red;
  height:150px;
  
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <span >Total</span>
    <i class="cat-color fa fa-circle" style="color: darkorange" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span>11</span>
</div>
```

these are just 2 solutions. there are more...but you should be able to achieve what you want using one of these 2. Let me know if it works

Comment: try giving a height to the outer divs and both your demos are not working I guess.. could you please check?

Comment: changed both of my answers with `height:150px` . for the first example you need to set the height to the `span` element and `display:inline-block` . and in the second example it works with `top` and `height:150px` on `div`

Comment: but , especially with the second solution you can change that `top:80%` to whatever you want and it works like a charm. not sure why are you saying that it's not working

Comment: rather my point was that the demo needs to be adjusted to be centered by say adjusting a specific property. Well, i agree with you :)